# Session value persist even after the value is unset PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have a problem resetting the value of session variable in PHP.

I cleared All my browser cookies and cache and load a page.
The controller of the page is called where the following code is written :

```
if(isset($_SESSION['event_generic_sequence'])){
        unset($_SESSION['event_generic_sequence']);
}
$_SESSION['event_generic_sequence'] = array();
```

This controllers calls a function in class file where it checks if the session is set and then value is appended to session:

```
$_SESSION['event_generic_sequence'][] = $image_name;
```

At the end of controller if the session value is printed, I get an array of having 4 values . Thus the count of array is 4:

```
[event_generic_sequence] => Array
    (
        [0] => 505_c.jpg
        [1] => 505_c-1.jpg
        [2] => 505_c-2.jpg
        [3] => 505_c-3.jpg
    )
```

When i reload the page. The controller gets called and the session value is set to blank array. But in class file if I print the session value . It shows the previous value of session. Why is class file not getting the current session value and the value of session seems to have been cached ?

If i clear the browser cookie and cache , The session value is blank and works fine. But if i don't the last value of session persist.

Comment: Please provide some more code/information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `session_start();` to start a session and `session_destroy();` to destroy the session else set the session of that particular variable to null or empty.

Comment: session_start() is used in index page at start. I cannot use that in class file again. Gives Notice "Session has already started" . I don't want to destroy whole session. Just want to reset a particular variable.